# Current plugins for padding in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, padding

I've been looking for hours to find a plugin that would add somthing like "padding: 5px" to an image. Does everyone do this through plain html? Our customer need a way to add this simply with the use of a button or right click context menu. Any suggestions/solutions or do I have to develop this myself?

Suggestions concerning other products than TinyMCE is not necessary.

Comment: Do you want to have it on button click only or just for every image in the editor? Is it desired to have it in the editor content later on or just for the appearance in the edit mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest to use is to add a custom stylesheet which only need to be set as a parameter ([content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css)). Example code snippet for the tinymce configuration:

```
...
theme: 'advanced',
content_css: "http://my_server/my_css/my_custom_css_file.css",
...
```

This css should contain something like the following

```
img {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

The code for the tinymce button is a bit more complex (but if wised i can post it as well) and the css gets set using the following

```
$(ed.get('my_editor_id').getBody()).find('img').css('padding-left','5px');
```

**UPDATE:** Button code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
          ed.addButton ('wrap_div', {
            'title' : 'my title',
            'image' : 'my_image.png',
            'onclick' : function () {
                ed.getBody().find('img').css('padding-left','5px');
            }
        });
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Great, this answers my question! Could I get some code for the button I would be very happy :) It would help out a lot since this is my first implementation of TinyMCE.